# JS/Knockout Endless Scrolling - Scroll Bar Jumps To Top of Page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scroll, infinite-scroll

So I have a chunk of code written in js that more or less checks the position of the scrollbar relative to the document/window size. If it is near the bottom, it will trigger a function call.

Everything was good up until I started coding the function that will actually load the extra pages/data underneath the currently shown data.

Here is what is written so far in the function that loads the extra data:

```
var appendData = function () {
    _loading(true);
    spinner.spin(spinnerTarget);
    FC.WebAPI.RouteTemplates.GetTemplates({ "criteria": _searchTerm(), "pageNumber": dataGridViewModel.currentPage(), "pageSize": dataGridViewModel.pageSize(), "filter": Filter.toODataString(filterViewModel.selectedFilters()), "orderBy": _getSortODataString() }).execute(function (response) {
        _data.concat(response.Results);
        spinner.stop();
        _loading(false);
        if (_searchTerm().trim() != "") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var terms = _searchTerm().split();
                for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
                    $('.routedetails span').highlight(terms[i]);
                }
            }, 200);
        }

    }, function (fail) {
        spinner.stop();
        _loading(false);
    });
}
```

This was used as a simple Next button prior to implementing the endless scroll feature, and to keep everything on the same page rather than loading a new one, we added the

```
_data.concat(response.Results);
```

Whenever the function gets called, and it does, it seems to jump the scroll bar to the top of the screen rather than keeping the same position, more or less. Not sure why it does that any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue once, and it was because there was a control at the top of the screen that had the focus. I called $(element).blur() on that control during the load page process and the problem went away.